# Check always location services are enabled or not in React Native (iOS and Android both)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, geolocation

I am working on react native application. There I have to fetch user locations like multiple if user moves/navigates from one place to other. This is working fine, but, If user disables location permission after some time like user goes to settings there disabled permission, I have to show some button like enable location and again Once user tap on that button It should ask to Request Permission for location.

But, If user first time gives permission and later in some time if he disables permission, The popup for Request permission not showing popup in Android on tap of button.

I am using following library to fetch user location details.

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

// button on click method following
  enableLocationHandler = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      this.requestLocationPermissions();
    } else {
      Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
      this.getLatitudeLongitude();
    }
  }



requestLocationPermissions = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        this.getLatitudeLongitude();
    } else {
      Geolocation.requestAuthorization();
      this.getLatitudeLongitude();
    }
  }



 getLatitudeLongitude() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
    },
      (error) => {
        if (error.code === 1) {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Location permission is denied', isLoading: false });
          Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
        }
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, distanceFilter: 100, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
    this.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      // this.showLoader();
      // console.log('position', position);
    });
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If Android is the same as iOS then the permission request is only shown once. If the user changes the permissions in the device settings then they have to change them back in the same place. All you can do is show an alert requesting the user goes ba k into settings to enable location permission

Answer (score 2):

IN this plugin react-native-geolocation-service, There is no declared run time permission in android.  that's by in android , permission dialog is not showing .

To resolve this issue add this permission before request for fetch location

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

async function requestAccessLocationPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Application wants location Permission',
        message:
          'Application wants location Permission',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    } else {
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

this will helps you, it helps me.